# Deploy war file to heroku including additional files

Tags: java, heroku, deployment, war

I am deploying a `war` file to `heroku` and want to include additional `properties` file to the slug as described here:

[Configuring WAR Deployment with the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt#including-files)

```
$ heroku war:deploy application.war --app awesomeapp --jdk 14 --includes app1.properties
```

It deploys `war` file successfully, but in any subfolder of the expanded application I can't find `app1.properties` file. At the same time all other files from `war` archive are on their places, additional `tomcat` `war-tracker` file, and nothing more. I tried to add some `jar` file with same result:

```
$ heroku war:deploy application.war --app awesomeapp --jdk 14 --includes app1.properties:some-lib.jar
```

**Question:** Where does heroku include additional files? How to get access there?

This is the output of the [heroku-cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli):

```
Uploading application.war
-----> Packaging application...
       - app: awesomeapp
       - including: app1.properties
       - including: some-lib.jar
       - including: webapp-runner.jar
       - including: application.war
-----> Creating build...
       - file: slug.tgz
       - size: 30MB
-----> Uploading build...
       - success
-----> Deploying...
remote:
remote: -----> heroku-deploy app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 14... done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 96.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v14
remote:        https://awesomeapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
-----> Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files will be added to the root of your Heroku application and won't be put into the expanded application directory.

You can verify your file is present in your Dynos by running `heroku run "cat app1.properties"`. If you want to explore the file system yourself, `heroku run bash` allows you to delve though it.

**Edit:**
If you need a path to the file, you can construct one using

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "app1.properties";
```